# What do they have in common?

Tags: riddle, pattern

What is the link between an astronotical fish, an owner of crown jewels, Chelsea, an honoured Akira, and a synthesizer?

Hint 1:

> The link is a name

Hint 2:

> A wilde name

Comment: Is "astronotical" in fact how you intend that to be spelled?

Comment: Yes it is not a misspelling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> **Oscar**

for the following reasons:

> astronotical fish  ->  astronotus ocellatus = oscar fish
>  an owner of crown jewels ->   Oscar of Sweden (King of Sweden and Norway, 1799-1859)
>  Chelsea ->  Oscar dos Santos Emboaba Junior (plays for Chelsea)
>  an honoured Akira ->  Oscar academy award for Akira Kurosawa
>  a synthesizer ->  OSCar synthesizer (by the Oxford Synthesiser Company)

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 8):

My guess:

> Kurosawa / Kurozawa

Reasons:

> Akira Kurosawa is apparently a Chelsea fan. Kurozawa is a synthesizer. There is a movie Jellyfish by K. Kurosawa. Akira Kurosawa's Seven samurais is often reffered to as the crown jewel of Japanese film.

Comment: You are so close, but it is sadly not correct

Answer (score 3):

Hrm.. tricky...

> They are all masters of their domain

Astronotical fish

> Master of the stars

Owner of crown jewels

> Ruler of a kingdom

Chelsea

> Might be subjective, but masters of the pitch?

Honoured Akira

> Oragami master

syntheziser

> Master of all things musical or sound

Comment: Good try, but the solution is easier than that.

Answer (score 3):

Well I doubt it's correct, but here goes:

> Dragon

Reasoning:

Astronotical fish

> Blank, because I have no idea where you're going with astronotical. Dragons are kinda like huge, flying, fire-spewing fish though.

Owner of crown jewels

> Dragons hoard gold and jewels, I guess? There's an obvious link somewhere I feel I forgot.

Chelsea

> The thing on the crest (of the football club) has a dragon look going on.

Honoured Akira

> Toriyama, creator of Dragon Ball.

synthesizer

> Apparently, Synthesizer is [a boss in some Dragon Ball game](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Synthesizer).

Comment: Good try, but not correct... Will post additional hints later today if necessary