# What is the common link?

Tags: riddle, pattern

What is the common link between

- an extraterrestrial entity,
- a space traveller,
- Michael Douglas,
- a friend of Thomas,
- a friend of Tony,
- an Army infantry regiment,
- and some naked ladies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This puzzle is very similar in spirit to [ [What do they have in common?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8811/what-do-they-have-in-common) ].

The answer is

> **Gordon** $~~~$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon)

for the following reasons:

- an extraterrestrial entity

  > **Gordon** Shumway (TV series ALF)
- a space traveller

  > **Gordon** Cooper (astronaut)
- Michael Douglas

  > **Gordon** Gekko (Douglas' character in movie "Wallstreet")
- a friend of Thomas

  > Thomas and **Gordon** (the tank engines)
- a friend of Tony

  > **Gordon** Brown (successor of Tony Blair)
- an Army infantry regiment

  > The **Gordon** Highlanders  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Highlanders
- and some naked ladies

  > **Gordon** (title of first album of the "Barenaked Ladies").